# unable to receive responce of query inserted by the form data in Phonegap

Tags: android, json, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have tried to replicate one of the programmers code in Phonegap.
aim of this project is to send form data to mysql database which is in remote.

I have succeeded to post form data to mysql server, but unable to receive response of query upon sucess or failure.
and also in the page of readjson i was trying to retrieve the list of records details using json.php, even this was not working.

Can any one please help on this .

Thanks in Advance.

code is as follows,
Index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.css" />
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--  -->          app.initialize();
<!-- -->
            $(document).ready(function()
             {
                 $("#insert").click(function(){
                     var title=$("#title").val();
                     var duration=$("#duration").val();
                     var price=$("#price").val();
                     var dataString="title="+title+"&duration="+duration+"&price="+price+"&insert=";
                     alert(dataString);
                        if($.trim(title).length>0 & $.trim(duration).length>0 & $.trim(price).length>0)
                             {
                                 $.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 url:"http://add2ads.com/jimson/database/insert.php",
                                 data: dataString,
                                 crossDomain: true,
                                 cache: false,
                                 beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
                        success: function (response,status) {
                                console.log(response.etat);
                        var data=json.parse(response)        
                        $.each(data, function(i, item){ 
                                    if ((item.etat == 'Success')) {
                                         $("#insert").val('submit');                        
                                    } else {
                                        alert("error");
                                        console.log(item.etat);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                                });
                            }return false;
                 });
             });
        </script>
        <title>Hello- you are at index.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
            <h1 class="title">Insert Database(index.html)</h1>
             <a class="button button-clear" href="readjson.html">Read JSON</a>
        </div><br/><br/>
        <div class="list">
        <form id="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">
             <input type="hidden" id="id" value=""/>
             <div class="item">
                <label>Emp ID (DRF/C)</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
             </div>
             <div class="item">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration"/>
             </div>
             <div class="item">
                 <label>Password</label>
                 <input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
             </div>
             <div class="item">
                <input type="button" id="insert" class="button button-block" value="Insert"/>
             </div>
        </form>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include "db.php";

  if(isset($_POST['title']))
 {
     $title=$_POST['title'];
     $duration=$_POST['duration'];
     $price=$_POST['price'];

     $q=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reg (emp_id,emp_name,emp_password) VALUES ('$title','$duration','$price')");

     if($q){
      echo "Successful";
     }else{
      echo "Error";
    }
  //echo "</br> ".mysql_error();
 }
 ?>
```

readjson.html

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.css" />
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function()
                 {
                 var url="http://add2ads.com/jimson/database/json.php";
                 $.getJSON(url,function(result){
                     console.log(result);
                     $.each(result, function(i, field){
                         var id=field.id;
                         var title=field.title;
                         var duration=field.duration;
                         var price=field.price;
                         $("#listview").append("<a class='item' href='form.html?id="+id+"&title="+title+"&duration="+duration+"&price="+price+"'><span class='item-note'>$"+price+"</span><h2>"+ title + " </h2><p>"+ duration +"</p></a>");
                     });
                 });
             });
         </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
     <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear">Home</a>
     <h1 class="title">Read Database (READJSON)</h1>
 </div><br/><br/>
 <ul class="list" id="listview"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

json.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include "db.php";
$data=array();

// Connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ('Not Connecting to the database');
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ('Not accessing table'); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reg";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result)
 die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error()); 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: in the ajax call, after success add ,
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      } and see what error it throws.

Comment: If i am not wrong i done in the same was you have suggested, but received no errors,  should i go with any other alternative?             success: function (response,status) {       console.log(response.etat);
var data=json.parse(response)        
$.each(data, function(i, item){ 
if ((item.etat == 'Success')) {
$("#insert").val('submit');                        
} else {
alert("error");
console.log(item.etat);
}
});
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status);
alert(thrownError);
}

Comment: I couldnt see error block in ajax call in readjson.html. Use $.ajax.

Comment: plz check once what code you have post  and what you have written in the comment.and one mistake I found that json.parse should be JSON.parse

Comment: Dear banik, i have just added the error block after success, did see any error message upon adding this line while executed.

Comment: I can give you a quick fix, but in the end you will need to rewrite your code. Your architecture is wrong. Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). You are better off starting from scratch NOW.

Comment: Dear JEssMonroy650, pls share your quickfix. i will try my best reuse it.

Comment: Banik, after a vigorous trails i came to know that, error status is 200 and the error is "syntaxError: unexpected token c".  And now the data is stored into mysql database but the success message is returned back/or accepted from jquery. can help me on this.